# How to resize in Ubuntu 20.04 Filesystem Partition 1?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, ram

New user of Ubuntu and so far loving all the features!

I am booting it using VM. I have a small problem right now that I hope someone can help me with. My RAM or overall memory on partition 1 is running very low to the point where the browser is crashing. I followed the steps to expand my memory by powering off Ubuntu going into the VM interface then>file>Virtual Media Manager, and then moving the cursor forwards for more memory. But it seems like its just made for more free space but the main partition that everything is running on is still only 537MB. Like the image shows, when I use click on partition 1 and then the gears button I click on the resize option, but resize is shown to be at its maximum 537MB the cursor is all the way at the end. All the other partitions shown allow for themselves to be expanded/resized. But I think everything is drawing from that single partition. Actually, I am not sure where those other partitions came from. I'd just like to be working with one partition and have it use the free space when needed.

Any advice on how to fix is greatly appreciated.

[image]

VM summary page below:
[image]

Comment: *Memory* (RAM) and *Storage* (Hard Drive) have different jobs. Changing one will not change the other. 537 MB of RAM is not enough to run Ubuntu. Re-partitioning storage will not increase RAM available for use.

Comment: @user535733 so where it says partition 1 is the RAM?  not the actual hard drive? because I keep getting warnings about low disc space? says it is at 0.2%

Comment: Low Disk Space is a *storage* (Disk) problem. It has nothing to do with *memory* (RAM). Your RAM (memory) is not shown among your Disk (storage) partitions. Partition 1 is your EFI partition for booting. Do not touch it.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the image of the VM summary in VirtualBox? This will show information like how many CPU cores and how much memory is allocated. With this information, it will become easier to provide a solution to your problem 

Comment: You have only used 0.2% of partition 1 so that is not a problem. Ubuntu is probably installed on partition 5 which is 10GB. That’s enough to start using a fresh install but not enough once you start adding stuff! You probably need to expand partition 2 and then expand partition 5. Search on here for how to resize with Gparted

Comment: @matigo ok just added!

Comment: @PonJar Make sense. New to linux and found Gparted kind of nebulous and hard to understand. Could I instead use Show Application>Disc>go to volumes>click the gears and resize there? How much should I resize partition 2 and expand partition 5?

Comment: @user535733 Thanks. The part that says Filesystem Partition 2 537MB that is basically Ubuntu's OS loader/booter? What would CD/DVD Drive VBOC CD-ROM be? when I look at disks in the finder I see that on the left-hand panel and it has 61MB in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any data that you cannot afford to lose on the VM back it up before doing any of the following.

You cannot resize your partitions while partition 5 is running Ubuntu so shut it down. What you need to do then is download the Ubuntu iso (installation media) to your host machine. Then you remove the VB Guest Additions from the virtual CD-ROM and insert the Ubuntu iso. Then change the boot priority of the VM so that it boots from the CD-ROM and choose “Try Ubuntu” not install Ubuntu. That will take you into a live environment where normally I’d say use GParted to resize your partitions. However you can probably use the disks app to do it if you prefer. I’ve not done it that way before but it should work. Resize partition 2 first, allowing it to use all the available space. Then resize partition 5 and use all the available space again.

Good luck, let us know how you get on.